# Excel using filling columns from rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, label, auto-form-fill

I have no idea how to title this so others will have easier time to search for this topic.

Let's say I have a table in sheet1 containing: title, first name, last name, street name, city and zip code. In sheet2 I can use CONCATENATE or references to the cells to create a combination of all these values to create an address label for an envelope. In sheet2 I'm using page layout to get a better view of how they will be printed, adjust the cell sizes and margins.

Let's say that sheet2 page has 8 rows and 3 columns. I can fill the 1st column by dragging the cell autofill, but then I get to the end of the page, to fill the next column I need to copy the formula from the last row of 1st column and manually change the data to be +1 and then drag again. Like: `=CONCATENATE(Sheet1!A9;" ";Sheet1!B9;" ";Sheet1!C9;CHAR(10);Sheet1!D9)` to `=CONCATENATE(Sheet1!A10;" ";Sheet1!B10;" ";Sheet1!C10;CHAR(10);Sheet1!D10)`
and then drag it till the end of the column and again change the formula.

Is there any way to fill all the cells from top left to bottom right automatically?
[image: example image]

I'd like to avoid VBA if possible.

Comment: The simplest way to achieve what you are trying to do would be with a Mail Merge in word. Open up word and choose a labels template. Set the data source to your excel sheet and it will automatically fill the labels in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to :

> "8 rows and 3 columns"

And assuming the the 1st row,1st column cell is A1.. So you last cell (3rd col, 8th row) will be C8 .

So instead of `Sheet1!A9` , use `indirect("Sheet1!A"&(9+(COLUMN(A1)-1)*8+ROW(A1)-1)` .. so you full formula will be :

```
=CONCATENATE(Sheet1!Aindirect("Sheet1!A"&(9+(COLUMN(A1)-1)*8+ROW(A1)-1));" ";Sheet1!Bindirect("Sheet1!A"&(9+(COLUMN(A1)-1)*8+ROW(A1)-1));" ";Sheet1!Cindirect("Sheet1!A"&(9+(COLUMN(A1)-1)*8+ROW(A1)-1));CHAR(10);Sheet1!Dindirect("Sheet1!A"&(9+(COLUMN(A1)-1)*8+ROW(A1)-1)))
```